# powershell choice menu (do-until) does not exit

Tags: powershell

```
function showMenu {
    cls;
    write-host “my menu”;
    write-host “1... Programm1”;
      write-host “2... Programm1”;
      write-host “3... Programm1”;
      write-host “q...exit”;
      return read-host "it´s your choice"
      }




$x = showMenu
do {showMenu}
until ($x -eq ‘q’)
```

From my understanding with return read-host "it´s your choice" I return a possible variable which i then defined as $x, the script works at its first execution, but after having entered something else than 'q' it just does not leave the loop

I´ve already googled a bit but only found stuff about people using infinite loops, and my books didn´t return anything i could use.

tl;dr: i got a loop that does exit at first but not after the further loops..

Comment: You aren't assigning to x inside the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning `$x` outside of the `do...until` loop, this means that if the user doesn't select the quit option the first time around, `$x` will never equal `'q'` and the loop is endless.

Simply move the assignment inside the `do` script block and the loop will exit when the user chooses `q`:

```
function showMenu {
    cls;
    write-host “my menu”;
    write-host “1... Programm1”;
      write-host “2... Programm1”;
      write-host “3... Programm1”;
      write-host “q...exit”;
      return read-host "it´s your choice"
      }


do {$x = showMenu}
until ($x -eq ‘q’)
```